# Wie schreibt man polnische Namen? (Grzegorz Brzęczyszczykiewicz)

Tags: spelling, person-names, diacritic

Wie schreibt man im Deutschen polnische Namen wie z.B. Grzegorz Brzęczyszczykiewicz?

> Gschegosch Bschenschytschykewitsch?

Ich bin unsicher besonders bei der Wiedergabe von rz -> sch.

Kontext: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfKZclMWS1U  (Szene aus einem Spielfilm)

Comment: Ich sehe keine Grund, auf eine Lautschrift-artige Umschreibung zurückzugreifen. Außer ein normales *e* statt dem e mit Ogonek finde ich keinen Änderungsbedarf.

Comment: Ich glaube das hängt extrem von der Zielgruppe ab. Leute mit Polnisch-Kenntnissen werden wissen, dass *rz* als stimmhaftes *sch* (wie in Garage das zweite *g*) ausgesprochen wird, allen anderen wird das *sch* vielleicht helfen aber dann wird es stimmlos, wie im Deutschen üblich, ausgesprochen werden.

Comment: Seit Bernhard Grzimek weiß man das hierzulande.

Comment: @Raketenolli ... und außerdem ist die deutschsprechende Normalbevölkerung gar nicht an Grapheme gewohnt, die stimmhafte Zischlaute wiedergeben würden. Slavisten sind das gewöhnt, aber die brauchen auch keine Umschrift.

Comment: Das interessiert mich auch

Comment: @Janka und neben dem berühmten Zoologen dürfte auch das *Przewalski-Pferd* hinreichend bekannt sein.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Es ist im professionellen Schriftsatz nicht üblich, Namen, die in der Ursprungssprache mit lateinischem Alphabet geschrieben werden, im Deutschen irgendwie anders zu schreiben als in der Ursprungssprache.

> Grzegorz bleibt Grzegorz.

Was hin und wieder vorkommt, ist, dass bestimmte Verlagshäuser in ihren Printprodukten noch nicht den vollen Satz aller möglichen Sonderzeichen haben; oder sie halten ihre Leser für zu dumm, mit Diakritika aus anderen Sprachen umzugehen (wie lange Zeit die Süddeutsche Zeitung, im Gegensatz zur FAZ); und darum fehlt z.B. bei türkischen Namen manchmal ein Häkchen unter s und t oder ein Schüsselchen auf einem g, das dort eigentlich hingehört. (Die Liste der Beispiele lässt sich endlos erweitern).

> Erdoğan wird zur Not Erdogan
>
> Brzęczyszczykiewicz wird zur Not Brzeczyszczykiewicz

Mehr und mehr Verlage gehen aber dazu über, die Originalschreibung zu verwenden, seit dies auch technisch eigentlich kein Problem mehr ist.

Ich halte es außerdem für ein Gebot der Höflichkeit und Achtung gegenüber den anderen Sprachen.

Schwieriger wäre die Frage zu beantworten, wenn es um Herkunftssprachen mit anderen Alphabeten ginge (Kyrillisch, Griechisch, Armenisch, Georgisch...)

Comment: Wenn ich nach "Lech Walesa" oder "Solidarnosc" google, finde ich sehr viele Treffer mit *le* anstelle von *łę* bzw. *sc* anstelle von *ść*. Deshalb bin ich nicht sicher, ob der erste Absatz die Realität richtig beschreibt.

Comment: Das wiederum liegt an "Nutzern" selbst - oft ist es fehlendes Bestreben ("sieht doch gleich aus") oder fehlendes Werkzeug (verfassen per Bildschirmtastatur). Entsprechend oft finde ich den Namen "Rene" statt "René".

Comment: @DavidVogt  Meine Antwort bezog sich bewusst auf Sprachpraxis durch Schriftsprachprofis (Verlage, Zeitungen, Journalisten, Schriftsteller, Wissenschaft). Was Nichtprofis so alles tun - denen das Internet heute die Möglichkeit gibt, öffentlich zu schreiben (und dadurch auch in Suchmaschinen aufzuscheinen) - hielt ich hier nicht einer Kommentierung wert. Aber auch diese werden kaum polnisches łę durch *wen* ersetzen, um sich mit den ärmlichen Mitteln des ASCII-Zeichensatzes der polnischen Aussprache anzunähern.

Comment: Die Treffer, auf die ich mich beziehe, sind auf Nachrichtenseiten.

Comment: Nach professionellem Schriftsatz war aber nicht gefragt.

Comment: Ich finde es an sich auch vernünftiger, in Fachpublikationen oder Qualitätszeitschriften die Originalzeichen beizubehalten, aber ich halte es für verkürzt, zu behaupten, dass Verlage sie weglassen, weil sie die Leser für zu dumm halten, damit umzugehen. Das ist letztlich eine haltlose Behauptung, die die Qualität diese ansonsten sehr guten Antwort eher senkt als hebt.

Answer (score 4):

Polnische Namen werden grundsätzlich genauso behandelt wie Namen aus beliebigen anderen Sprachen mit lateinischer Schrift.

- Falls ein Name aus Zeichen besteht, die es auch im Deutschen gibt, wird der Name original übernommen. 
   (Mallorca wird nicht zu "Majorka" und Bordeaux nicht zu "Bordoh")
- Falls ein Name im Deutschen unbekannte Zeichen enthält, werden diese meistens umgewandelt, zum Beispiel: å → a, ç → c, ï → i, ł → l, ő → ö.

In den letzten Jahren sieht man vermehrt, dass solche Zeichen beibehalten werden, das stellt m.E. aber außer bei einigen Worten wie *à la carte* (kein Restaurant, das etwas auf sich hält, würde auf das *à* verzichten) oder in "wissenschaftlicheren" Texten noch immer eine **Ausnahme** dar.

Ich halte das **weder für ein Zeichen von Ignoranz oder mangelnden Respekts, sondern für eine (wackelnde) Konvention**: *"In deutschen Texten kommen nur Buchstaben vor, die auch im deutschen Alphabet vorhanden sind."*

Folglich:

> Grzegorz Brzęczyszczykiewicz → Grzegorz Brz**e**czyszczykiewicz

- Vielfach wird der Vorname lokalisiert. Louis XIV wird im Deutschen Ludwig XIV. genannt und Queen Elizabeth Königin Eli**s**abeth (oder Queen Elizabeth). Aus Grzegorz würde dann Gregor (z.B. in einem Roman oder im privaten Umfeld).

> Grzegorz Brzęczyszczykiewicz → **Gregor** Brz**e**czyszczykiewicz